# Matching Two Tables Document types

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlite

I have two table.

```
FD_Documents
FICA11
```

In FD_Documents there are two columns FD_CBAF8917 = Document type and FD_B61DDE99 = ID_Number

```
***sample data***
2456525425625,other
2456525425625,id
2456525425625,POA
2456522456585,other
2456522456585,id
1245879566554,poa
1245879566554,ID
```

In FICA11

In FICA11 there are two columns DOC_TYPE = Document type and ID_NUMBER = ID_Number

```
***sample data***
2456525425625,other
2456525425625,id
2456525425625,POA
2456522456585,other
2456522456585,id
1245879566554,poa
1245879566554,ID
```

Now I need to match ID number to ID Number and bring back records that have a gold match on document type (Meaning have of Golden match, has all three unique document types, other id, poa?

is this possible?

Thank you

```
SELECT top 10 
   FD_Documents.FD_B61DDE99, 
   count(DISTINCT FD_Documents.FD_CBAF8917) as type_matches
FROM 
   FD_Documents INNER JOIN 
   FICA11 ON FD_Documents.FD_B61DDE99 = FICA11.ID_NUMBER 
          AND FD_Documents.FD_CBAF8917 = FICA11.DOC_TYPE
GROUP BY FD_Documents.FD_B61DDE99
ORDER BY count(DISTINCT FD_Documents.FD_CBAF8917) desc


    SELECT  FD_Documents.FD_B61DDE99,FD_Documents.FD_CBAF8917, FICA11.DOC_TYPE
    FROM    FD_Documents INNER JOIN
            FICA11 ON FD_Documents.FD_B61DDE99 = FICA11.ID_NUMBER
```

Comment: Consider adding sample data via sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you all ids with golden match:

```
SELECT d.id 
FROM 
  FD_Documents d INNER JOIN  
  FICA11 f ON d.id = f.id AND d.type = f.type
GROUP BY d.id
HAVING COUNT(distinct d.types) = 3
```

To see the output per ID, try this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 d.id, COUNT(distinct d.types) as type_matches
FROM 
  FD_Documents d INNER JOIN  
  FICA11 f ON d.id = f.id AND d.type = f.type
GROUP BY d.id
ORDER BY COUNT(distinct d.types) DESC
```

Comment: hi @Bulat- error level 15, state1, line 3, incorrect syntax near keyword 'BY

Comment: it runs successfully but, give no results, but i know there are golden matches, but counting them will take me forever, i have even changed the 3 to a 2  also no results.

Comment: move `COUNT(distinct d.types)` from `having` to `select` and get top rows to see what you get.

Comment: Do you get anything for simple INNER JOIN of two tables on ID or both ID and type

Comment: if you join on both ID and Type like this: `INNER JOIN  
  FICA11 f ON d.id = f.id AND d.type = f.type` ??

Comment: i have added the code i ran in the first post, please see if im doing it correct?

Comment: the query where i get the 1016595 is to show me what documents I have, the second one, i need to see how many matches i can make?